# Как запустить iscsi через pacemaker?

Tags: linux, cluster

Всем привет. Запутался я в вопросе кластеризации. Помогите пожалуйста.
Во всех мануалах которые я прочитал якобы pacemaker сам создает target и lun. Но что-то у меня он просто выдает ошибку при запуске. Так вот я не могу понять он создает сам конфигурацию iscsi или я ее должен создать руками на обоих нодах?

А архитектура такая: два компьютера, на них поднят drbd раздел. На этом разделе создан lvm. И lvm раздел я уже хочу выпустить в сеть и чтоб pacemaker просто перекидывал ресурсы с сервера на сервер если один вдруг умер.

Answer (score 1):

Да, pacemaker сам содает iscsi target. Поставил targetcli, им очень удобно вручную создавать iscsi таргеты, в pacemaker при создании ресурса lun указывается что тип iot-t. И все отлично работает, почти =)